# NativeScript: How to make TabView menu shrink, to fit the device width?

Tags: css, nativescript

I have a TabView with three TabViewItems, something like that:

```
  <TabView   :selectedIndex="selectedTab" @selectedIndexChange="onTabChange">
      <TabViewItem  title="Add new images">
         some content...
      </TabViewItem>
      <TabViewItem title="Backedup images">
        some content...
      </TabViewItem>
      <TabViewItem title="Manage categories">
       some content...
      </TabViewItem>

    </TabView>
```

The problem is that the tab menu "spills" off screen:
[image: spill]
As you can see, the third tab is visible partially, due to the long title.

Is there a way to force tab items to "respect" the device width, while shrinking the font size of the titles accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct API exposed to adjust the Tab width, but you may able to achieve this by adjusting the layout params on the native view.

If you like to allocate equal width for each tab, divide your screen width by number of tabs. Run the code below in the loaded event of your TabView.

```
import { isIOS, isAndroid, screen } from 'tns-core-modules/platform';

onTabViewLoaded: function(args) {
    var tabView = args.object;
    if (isAndroid) {
        var nativeTabView = tabView._tabLayout.getChildAt(0),
            width = screen.mainScreen.widthPixels / nativeTabView.getChildCount();

        for (let i = 0; i < nativeTabView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            const view = nativeTabView.getChildAt(i),
                layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();

            layoutParams.weight = 0;
            layoutParams.width = width;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
        nativeTabView.invalidate();
    }
}
```